# $routeProvider is not working properly in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

var app = angular.module('TaskApp', []);

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/Home', {
        templateUrl: '/Home/Index',
        controller: 'IndexController'
    });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    //$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');

}]);
```

This code is not working properly ,When I remove $routeProvider all reference it work properly but I need $routeProvider how I solve it ?

Comment: your arguments are swapped

Comment: Thanks corn,
I swapped argument but problem is still yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', 
    function ($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
```

Oops

*EDIT*

```
 var app = angular.module('TaskApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

You also need to add the route service to the app.

Comment: Thanks corn, I swapped argument but problem is still yet

Comment: @DineshPipple did adding the ngRoute help. you will also need to add it in the path for your scripts. Not sure what version of Angular you're using https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

Comment: I add 'ngRoute' in my module and angular-route.min.js in my code route is working.
Now new problem is arise I define it my new question 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26536054/routing-is-automatically-reload-angularjs-and-hang-the-page?noredirect=1#comment41708034_26536054

Please take a look give your suggestion