# $routing is automatically reload angularjs and hang the page

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, asp.net-mvc-5.1

app.js file is

```js
 var app = angular.module('TaskApp', ['ngRoute']);
    app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/Home/Index', {
                controller: 'TaskManager',
                templateUrl: '/Home/Index'
            }).otherwise({ redirectTo: "/" });

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }]);

    app.controller('TaskManager', function () {
        //$location.path('/');
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="TaskApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <base href="/">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
    <body>
        <div ng-view></div>
      <a href="/Home/Index">Home </a>
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <h1> @Html.Label("Task Manager", new { @class = "heading" })</h1>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container body-content">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>

        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
        <script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/Page/app.js"></script>
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

        
    </body>
</html>
```

When i click on home link button then a lots of request is running and my page is hang give warning that :
WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.

I can't found what problem is in my code

Comment: It would help if we knew which code what in which files.

Comment: I give more detail about my code I a solution change <div ng-view><div> to <ui-view></ui-view> then 
WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once. is removed but it change full view not updating only ng-view which is not proper solution

Comment: First, please show _relevant_ code only - there is no need to see all that ASP.NET code. When you try to reduce your code to minimum while still reproducing the issue, miraculous thing happens - you most likely solve the issue yourself. If not, it would be easier to help you.

Comment: After edit I show only relevant code in under above comment I found a solution but it is not proper solution